# Slide menu controller like Facebook not working on Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode8

I followed a YouTube video to make a SlideMenuController but it shows errors on my Xcode8, I think maybe there're something changes to Swift?

[image: .]

Comment: Add code, not screenshot of code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spacing between `storyboard` and `?` to look like `storyboard?` in each of those problem lines and your issues should be solved.